# WebSocket can connect to local server, but can't send or receive

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm working on setting up a websocket between two local servers for development.

On one end I have my Ionic app running on http://localhost:8100/

On the other end I have a Spring backend running on http://localhost:9080/ (or http://127.0.0.1:9080)

Connection has been established, so next up I want to send a message to the websocket with a token (I know this can be send along when the connection is set up in SockJS 1.1.0, but I am currently using 0.3.4)

However my code in the backend doesn't seem to respond, I am wondering if my IP configuration is correct. I followed a tutorial and got this working in another project.

Anyone with more experience that knows if the url in the subscribe function also needs to be prefixed with 'localhost' or an IP adrress? I know the websocket changes from http:// to ws:// so I suppose when this is the case I need to prefix it with something like: ws://localhost:9080/...

Anyway, here's my code:

WebSocet Service :

```
function init() {
      var socket = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:9080/ws-notification');
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
          console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
          /**
           * Subscribe at /ws-topic/greetings url to catch messages
           */
          stompClient.subscribe('/ws-topic/greetings', function(greeting){
              notify(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
          });
          parseAuthentication();
      });
  }

  function parseAuthentication(){
      stompClient.send("/ws-app/ws-notification",{},JSON.stringify({ 'token': authenticationService.isAuthenticated() }));
  }


  function disconnect() {
      if (stompClient != null) {
          stompClient.disconnect();
      }
      // setConnected(false);
      console.log("Disconnected");
  }

  function notify(message){
      console.log("NOTIFY: "+message);
  }
```

The WebSocket Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-notification").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config){
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/ws-topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws-app");
    }
}
```

My Controllerfunction :

```
@MessageMapping("/ws-notification")
@SendTo("/ws-topic/greetings")
public Notify greeting(Notify notify) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    return new Notify("Hello, your token is :" + notify.getWsToken());
}
```

Notice that I only specify the IP adress when I set up the connection in the init() function, tried to prefix the other url's with ws://127.0.0.1:... but no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

The problem was that there was no default contructor method in the models I used to send the data.

This was also not implemented or mentioned in the [Spring WebSocket Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: Could you please explain how you fixed it exacly? The model I see in that tutorial do have default constructors. For me it is possible to send stuff to spring but I don't get anything back in the subscribed channels.

Comment: @JanWytze It's probably ther Object notify, it has a string constructor, so if he forgot to declared back the defalt constructor it won't exists and spring will fail.